# How to add a composite condition to ForAll?

Tags: functions, function-construction

I used Mathematica to prove that

$$\Gamma (z+1) = z \Gamma (z)$$

is true by showing

```
ForAll[z, Re[z] > 0, Gamma[z + 1] == z Gamma[z]] // Resolve
( True )
```

Now, I want to show that

$$\Gamma (z) = \frac {\Gamma (z+n)}{(z)_n}$$

is true for all Re(z)>0, n in N, by showing a similar ForAll but I do not know how to add the assumption that both Re(z)>0, n are in N.

Note that $(z)_n$ stands for Pochhammer[z,n]

My question is how to create a similar ForAll which resolves to true for the second identity.

Comment: I don't think it's true: `Gamma[z] == Gamma[z + n + 1]/Pochhammer[z, n] // FunctionExpand` gives `Gamma[z] == (n + z) Gamma[z]`.

Comment: I corrected that in the question, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[Gamma[z] == Gamma[z + n]/Pochhammer[z, n], 
 Assumptions -> Re[z] > 0 && n ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `(* True *)`

Comment: Works without assumptions too: `FullSimplify[Gamma[z] == Gamma[z + n]/Pochhammer[z, n]]` gives `True`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Gamma[z] == Gamma[z + n]/Pochhammer[z, n] // FunctionExpand
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: But only for n in N, surely? How can this restriction be added, do you know?

Comment: No, these functions all have [analytic continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation).

Comment: Gamma IS an analytic continuation, but does Pochhammer[z,n] has one too?

Comment: It all seems to work, this was quite a learning experience. - Yeah, analytic continuation defined in terms of Gamma. :-) - https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2#iii

Comment: The analytic continuation of `Pochhammer[z, n]` is literally defined through your equation as the ratio of two $\Gamma$ functions.